# Strange compiler complaint when using similar code

Tags: c, compiler-errors, user-input

For a project, I have to ask the user for a file name, and I'm reading it in character by character using `getchar`.

From the main, I call the function `char *coursename= introPrint(); //start off` to print the usage directions and get the first bit of input.  That function is defined as

```
char *introPrint(){
  int size= 20;
  int c;
  int length=0;
  char buffer[size];


  //instructions printout, cut for brevity

  //get coursename from user and return it
  while ( (c=getchar()) != EOF && (c != '\n') ){
    buffer[length++]= c;
    if (length==size-1)
      break;

  }
  buffer[length]=0;
  return buffer;
}
```

This is basically identical code I wrote to ask the user for input, replace the character echo with asterisks, then print out the results.  Here, though, I'm getting a `function returns address of local variable` warning for the return statement.  So why am I getting no warnings from the other program, but trigger one for this code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're returning the address of `buffer`, which is destroyed when it goes out of scope (when the function returns). When you try to use the returned pointer, the behavior of the program is undefined: the program may reuse the memory where the instance of  `buffer` was previously located for other purposes.

Use a `static` buffer, allocate one with `malloc` or let the caller pass in a buffer. In the last case, the function and its caller also need to communicate about the length of the buffer somehow (by an extra argument `size`, for example).

Comment: Make sense.  Is there an alternative other than making a global variable?\

Comment: Yes. allocating memory or using a static buffer.

Comment: Or just declare the buffer in the caller of the introPrint function and pass a pointer to it to the introPrint function

Comment: The third alternative is passing a buffer + len to the function.

Comment: Note that using a static buffer is non-reentrant. In any case, you should clearly document the ownership of the buffer.

Answer (score 1):

The warning tells you that you have stack memory (for your buffer object) inside your function and thus you should not access it from outside. Depending on the environment the memory used to save the input may be overwritten by other data when you want to use it.

It is better to define allocate memory to your coursename and then pass a pointer to your function or dynamically allocate the buffer memory.

Answer (score 1):

Because here, you really return pointer to a local (for the function's scope) var:
`char buffer[size];`

So, after the executing of the function, this array is destroyed and the pointer is invalid and you get undefined behavior.

To fix this, you should allocate the array dynamically, using `malloc`:

```
char* buffer = (char*)malloc( size * sizeof( char ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess that you didn't return a pointer to the buffer in the other function.

The problem is that all local variables are destroyed when the function returns. That means that the returned pointer doesn't point anywhere anymore. There is no buffer. Not good!

Answer (score 0):

when you declare char buffer[] it places that buffer on the stack. When the function exits, the stack is popped and the buffer ceases to exist. If you want to return a dynamic buffer, call malloc() (or GlobalAlloc() in windows, or optionally use the new operator in c++).

The static keyword will cause the buffer to exist outside the stack, essentially the same as a global, only not accessible outside the function.